# How to point to an OS X framework in a ruby extconf.rb file?

Tags: ruby, macos

I'd like to make this gem work on OS X Mavericks: https://github.com/drbrain/pasteboard/blob/master/ext/pasteboard/extconf.rb

Currently, installing this gem through `gem install pasteboard` fails, because `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework` doesn't exist anymore.

It now lives in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/HIServices.framework`

and 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/HIServices.framework`

Of course it would be dirty to replace one hardcoded string with another hardcoded string. I know I can get to the first part of the path (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`) by running `xcode-select -p`. But what about the rest of the path? Do I just test if I'm on 10.8 or 10.9 and then append the correct path or is there a cleaner way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I've figured it out:

```
xcrun --show-sdk-path
```

That gives me: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk`

So it ruby I can do this:

```
sdk_path = `xcrun --show-sdk-path`.strip
puts File.join(sdk_path, 'System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/HIServices.framework')
```

That should do the trick!